# Paragraph (Section) width changing size in Android Browser

Tags: android, css, html

I have created a website for a client that works on all web browsers as I intended except for Android. For reasons unknown the Android browser resizes my Menu bar as well as the  part depending which phone it is running on.

If you would like to see the code please go to [this link](http://tworoxdesign.com/EES/)

This is a screen shot from the Galaxy Nexus

[screen shot from Galaxy Nexus](http://tworoxdesign.com/images/Screen%20Shot%202013-03-19%20at%2001.12.13.png)

As you can see the text has been pushed into a tall thin column. I have no idea why it is doing this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Delete everything in the `#AboutUs` From the #AboutUs in Style.Css line 445.

**Before**

```
#AboutUs 
{
height: 655px;
}
```

**After**

```
#AboutUs 
{
}
```

As for the footer, remove the width from its css (#legal) (Line 693 in Style.CSS)

**Before**

```
#legal 
{
position: relative; 
font-size: 10px;
margin: 0px auto;
width: 130px;
padding: 0px;
line-height: 1.1em;
text-align: center;
color: #606060;
top: 5px;
}
```

**After**

```
#legal 
{
position: relative; 
font-size: 10px;
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 0px;
line-height: 1.1em;
text-align: center;
color: #606060;
top: 5px;
}
```